# understanding mysqlslap concurrency

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, errors, mysqlslap

I have a RDS instance running in AWS. By default

> max_connections=45

so I used mysqlslap to see how it works. I ran:

```
mysqlslap --concurrency=20 --host=deleteme.ckn5fsf3nwqp.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --user=deleteme --password --auto-generate-sql
```

and it worked nicely. Then I modified the --concurrency to 45, 50, 100, 150, 200 and it worked anyway, I was expecting a 'Too many connections' error, but I only see that error from --concurrency to over 300.

So my 1st question is, if my max_connections is set to 45, and using a concurrency of ~200 connections, how doesn't mysqlslap give me error?

I also tried this experiment running mysql in an EC2 instance. I tried --concurrency with 500 connections, and got the 'Too many connections error', but that error is not logged in /var/log/mysql. Is it a default configuration that mysql doesn't log those errors?

and my last question is again regarding RDS. I was hoping to see in cloudwatch, a spike on DB connections, but even using mysqlslap at concurrency=45, I only see 'DB Connection Count' metric to 1.

Maybe mysqlslap concurrency does not create new connections?

Comment: While mysqlslap was running more than 45 connections, what was in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?  What did these status values say: `Threads_running`, `Max_used_connections`, `Connection_errors_max_connections`, `Aborted_clients`, `Aborted_connects`?

Comment: What kinds of queries were run?  Look at the `Com%` STATUS values before and after -- to see how many were actually run.